# How do I display the text from a Rails AJAX JSON response - Javascript is returning [object HTMLDocument]

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails app where I created an AJAX / JSON controller to do some dynamic HTML updates in the view.  I followed this guide: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/

I make a call like this: `../related.json?vendor_id=1&budget_id=1` and it returns the raw HTML partial I want to update (just a bunch or table rows).

My call looks like this:

```
    Rails.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) { 
        document.getElementById("related").innerHTML = "data"
//        alert(data)
      }
    })
```

If I manually view the JSON request in the browser the HTML output is as expected.  However when I try to replace the HTML or even view the data in a test alert I get back `[object HTMLDocument]`.  The guide I followed used `data.html` to feed the innerHTML but that doesn't work for me.  Not sure if that's a UJS / JQuery issue.

How do I set that DOM element with the raw text from the JSON call?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a raw text to html with JSON.stringify function:

```
document.getElementById("related").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: That returns `{"location":null}`.  I double checked my JSON source - it is returning plain text (HTML) - on headers etc.  Just the <tr> rows.

Comment: Upvoted your answer because it made me think more about my controller side which was the ultimate answer.  . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and tried this in my controller:

```
format.json { render  partial: 'related' }
```

vs

```
format.json { render html: render_to_string( partial: 'related' ) }
```

This did the trick - I figured that I was feeding the JSON request the wrong data - looks like once I feed it raw text vs html it works fine.